# Scala: Get index in map function

Tags: scala, map-function

I am starting in Scala and I want to get an index while I am iterating over a list using the map function.

For example, I have this line of code:

```
val x= list.flatMap(l => anotherFunction(l.param1.param2List.size * l.multiplier, l, l.param1.param2List(0)))
```

And I wanted to do something like this:

```
val x= list.flatMap(l => anotherFunction(l.param1.param2List.size * l.multiplier, l, l.param1.param2List(index)))
```

Is there any way to add a counter or something like that in order to get the index as if I was looping through the list in a for cycle? Is it possible or should I try another approach?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use map and receive an index as well in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2213323/how-can-i-use-map-and-receive-an-index-as-well-in-scala)

Comment: it is a duplicate: i.e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363754/accessing-an-index-in-a-list-in-scala

Answer (score 1):

I am sure this is a duplicate, use something like:

```
val l = List(1, 2, 4)
val r = l.zipWithIndex
```

Please read api documentation on collections:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html

What exactly are you trying to achieve ?